# Material-UI collapse table with hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I've been trying to come around this issue with no luck, I need help with my handleClick() function where it collapses and expands all table rows at the same time as shown in this [CodeSandbox snippet](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-brook-epy8d?file=/src/MyTable.js). Any idea why is it behaving like so ? and how to fix it ?

2- Also when component mounts, it fires multiple times.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  Box,
  Collapse,
  IconButton,
  Table,
  TableBody,
  TableCell,
  TableContainer,
  TableHead,
  TableRow,
  Typography,
  Paper
} from "@material-ui/core";
import KeyboardArrowDownIcon from "@material-ui/icons/KeyboardArrowDown";
import KeyboardArrowUpIcon from "@material-ui/icons/KeyboardArrowUp";
import { v4 as uuid } from "uuid";

function CollapsibleTable() {
  const [fetchedData, setFetchedData] = useState([]);
  const [isLoding, setIsLoding] = useState(false);
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState();

  const getData = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2");
    const result = await response.json();
    setIsLoding(false);
    setFetchedData(
      result.data.map((user) => ({
        user_data: {
          id: user.id,
          firstName: user.first_name,
          lastName: user.last_name,
          email: user.email
        },
        other_data: {
          avatar: user.avatar
        }
      }))
    );
  };

  const handleClick = () => {
    setExpanded(!expanded);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <TableContainer component={Paper}>
      <Table size="small" aria-label="ccg">
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell />
            <TableCell>Index</TableCell>
            <TableCell>ID</TableCell>
            <TableCell>First Name</TableCell>
            <TableCell>Last Name</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Email</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {isLoding
            ? "Loading . . ."
            : fetchedData.map((user, index) => (
                <React.Fragment key={uuid()}>
                  <TableRow
                    style={{
                      borderBottom: "unset"
                    }}
                  >
                    <TableCell>
                      <IconButton
                        aria-label="expand row"
                        size="small"
                        onClick={handleClick}
                      >
                        {expanded ? (
                          <KeyboardArrowUpIcon />
                        ) : (
                          <KeyboardArrowDownIcon />
                        )}
                      </IconButton>
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                      {index}
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                      {user.user_data.id}
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                      {user.user_data.firstName}
                    </TableCell>

                    <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                      {user.user_data.lastName}
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="right">{user.user_data.email}</TableCell>
                  </TableRow>

                  <TableRow>
                    <TableCell
                      style={{ paddingBottom: 0, paddingTop: 0 }}
                      colSpan={6}
                    >
                      <Collapse
                        in={expanded}
                        timeout="auto"
                        unmountOnExit={true}
                      >
                        <Box margin={1}>
                          <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom component="div">
                            Txns History
                          </Typography>
                          <Table size="small" aria-label="purchases">
                            <TableHead>
                              <TableRow>
                                <TableCell>Avatar</TableCell>
                                <TableCell>Avatar</TableCell>
                              </TableRow>
                            </TableHead>
                            <TableBody>
                              <TableRow key={uuid()}>
                                <TableCell>
                                  <img
                                    style={{
                                      borderRadius: "50%",
                                      width: "50px"
                                    }}
                                    src={user.other_data.avatar}
                                    alt="avatar"
                                  />
                                </TableCell>
                                <TableCell>
                                  <img
                                    style={{
                                      borderRadius: "50%",
                                      width: "50px"
                                    }}
                                    src={user.other_data.avatar}
                                    alt="avatar"
                                  />
                                </TableCell>
                              </TableRow>
                            </TableBody>
                          </Table>
                        </Box>
                      </Collapse>
                    </TableCell>
                  </TableRow>
                </React.Fragment>
              ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  );
}

export default CollapsibleTable;
```

I've tried to toggle each one by it's index value like so

```js
const handleClick = (index) => {
    setExpanded({
      ...expanded,
      [index]: !expanded[index]
    });
  }

<Collapse in={expanded[index]} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit={true}>
   //...
</Collapse>
```

But still doesn't work as expected...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your `expanded` state is the state for all of the `Collapse` components.

This is what your component tree currently looks like after mapping:

```
<>
  <Collapse
    in={expanded}
  />
  <Collapse
    in={expanded}
  />
  <Collapse
    in={expanded}
  />
</>
```

So when the `expanded` state changes to true, then they are all expanded.

To solve this, you could have a different state for each of the `Collapse` components. In my example below, I used an array to store these boolean values. Such that if array element of index X is true, then collapse X should be expanded

```
const getData = async () => {
  ...
  // after you receive your data, initialize all expanded boolean to be false so they are all closed by default
  setExpanded([...Array(result.data.length)].map((val) => false));
}; 

<Collapse
  in={expanded[index]} // we use index to reference the correlated expanded state value
  timeout="auto"
  unmountOnExit={true}
>

<IconButton
  aria-label="expand row"
  size="small"
  onClick={() => handleClick(index)} // onClick pass the index clicked
>

// set new state depending on what Collapse index was clicked
const handleClick = (index) => {
  setExpanded(
    expanded.map((boolean_value, i) => {
      if (index === i) {
        // once we retrieve the collapse index, we negate it
        return !boolean_value;
      } else {
        // all other collapse will be closed
        return false;
      }
    })
  );
};
```

[image: Edit agitated-browser-wy3b5]